# array_rand() is returning integers from my indexed array instead of the values

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm having trouble pulling a random array value using PHP's `array_rand()` function. What am I doing wrong?!

```
$topics = array("1", "2", "3");
$colors = array("#ff3333", "#ffcc00", "#ccff33");

foreach ($topics as $t) {
    $c = array_rand($colors, 1);
    echo "style='color:$c'";
}
```

I'm getting integers returned, rather than my values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array_rand() returns the key for a random entry.

So you need to use `$colors[$c]`.

*Code:*

```
echo "style='color:$colors[$c]'";
```